# .net to coldfusion web service xml parsing

Tags: asp.net, xml, web-services, coldfusion

I have an .NET web service which I'm calling with the following code:

```
        <cfinvoke 
            webservice="http://server01/customer.asmx?WSDL"
            refreshwsdl="true"
            method="NotesList"
            returnvariable="aTemp">
                <cfinvokeargument name="SessionID" value="#arguments.SessionID#"/>
                <cfinvokeargument name="CustomerCode" value="#arguments.CustomerCode#"/>
        </cfinvoke>
```

The web service schema is as follows:

[image]

I want to extract the xml value in the "MessageXML" node.
If I dump out the return var "aTemp", I get the following:

[image]

How do I get the raw XML??

If I dump out the method getMessageXML(), I get the following:

[image]

How do I get the raw XML? I'm obviously missing something.

Comment: But ... aTemp is a `NotesListResponse` not a single variable. I don't think you can get there from here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#aTemp.MessageXML#
```

You might be able to use `#aTemp.getMessageXML().toString()#` too but I am pretty sure you can access the MessageXML directly although CF may have converted it to an XML object. In that case `#toString(aTemp.MessageXML)#` should work to get the raw XML.

Comment: Yes.  CF will automatically convert XML to an XML object and dump it as a struct.  Output it instead of dumping it, and you should see the string.  If you want to print the XML instead of use it as a data format, there are some nice XML formatters on http://cflib.org

Comment: I got there eventually using the following:
<cfset var Local = StructNew()>
<cfset Local.result = structNew() />
<cfset Local.aDataset = arguments.dataset.getMessageXML().get_any() />
<cfset Local.allXML = xmlParse(Local.aDataset[1]) />